# Strange Array#each Ruby behaviour

Tags: ruby

The question is a bit vague, but I am not really sure why this happens:

I have the following code:

```
p user.room.users.length
user.room.users.each {|usr| puts "b" }
user.room.users.each {|usr| puts "a"; usr.enter(Room[Config::entrance]) }
```

which outputs:

```
5
b
b
b
b
b
a
a
a
```

I also made User#enter count how many times it's been called and it returns `3`! I am completely baffled by this behaviour. I doubt the code within User#enter is the cause, but if someone thinks it might be relevant I can provide it (I don't want to clutter the question unnecessarily).

---

#### Edit

If it's relevant I am using `ruby-1.9.3-p125`

Comment: Try 5.times{ usr.enter(Room[Config::entrance]) } then you can distinguish where is the problem.

Comment: @megas But, I can't predict the user's so, that won't work. I suppose I can make it send all the users on the server into the room. *tries*

Comment: If the code in `usr.enter` changes `room.users`, it might very well be the problem. Of course for all we know, it's also possible that `room` simply returns a different object each time you call it, or users a different array. So yeah, we need to see more code.

Comment: @sepp2k Oh, that gave me an idea... I'll check and get back to you @megas: `User.list.values.each {|usr| puts "a"; usr.enter(Room[Config::entrance])}` actually worked!

Comment: @sepp2k Oh. This is embarrassing. I changed `user.room.users.each {|usr| puts "a"; usr.enter(Room[Config::entrance]) }` to `user.room.users.dup.each {|usr| puts "a"; usr.enter(Room[Config::entrance]) }` Want to respond so I can mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah, `enter` *did* modify `room.users`. I was living in the very vivid illusion that the array was duplicated before it was being iterated. There's not even a reason for me to think that, I simple did. Oh, well. Thanks! ♥

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of behavior often happens when you change a collection while iterating over it. So if `usr.enter` modifies `user.room.user` that would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

As @sepp2k said, presumably `usr.enter` is modifying `user.room.users`. Though I've never looked at the source, `Array#each` seems to work by maintaining an internal index for the current element, and incrementing that index after each iteration (indeed, that's the only reasonable way it *could* work).

So say you start with `[1,2,3]`, and on the first iteration of `#each`, you remove the first element. For the second iteration, it will yield the second element of the array, but now the array is `[2,3]`, so the second element is `3`. So you will miss an element.

Comment: Yeah, after writing a detailed test I figured that was what was happening. I was under the impression the array is internally duplicated and then iterated over. I had no particular reason to think that. =/